# Working with PHP and Mysql code in TWIG

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, twig

I am working with the TWIG framework for php, and would like to know how i would be able to include these php files inside my php code like i normally do.

```
<?php
session_start();

include("includes/db.php");
include("functions/searchfunctions.php");
include("functions/userSearchSession.php");

?>
```

The db file establishes the connection through mysqli to the database.

Comment: looks like you have some _serious_ misunderstandings of what TWIG is - it's a templating engine, not a framework. Start here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/intro.html#basic-api-usage

Comment: thanks for the clarification, in addition to being a templating engine, doesn't have its own custom templating language that you have to use. where if you just want the templating system you would use something like http://platesphp.com/

Comment: you dont put php in a twig template. thats one of the main points of twig which is a templating language.  Ideally you would use twig within an [MVC](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/article.php/3912211) framework such as [Symfony](http://symfony.com/).  You can use twig separately, but youll still need to be rolling your own MVC architecture.

Comment: It does, but all of that logic is taken care of when you call `$twig->render('twigtemplate.html.twig')` within the rest of your PHP script.

Comment: I am using slim framework as the MVC that works within twig. In that page there no php code, but how i wouldli include these php code into it. for instance that page is rendered as such $app->get('/category/:name', function ($name) use($app){
  $app->render("searchtest.php", ['name' => $name]);
});

Comment: @user3907211 Using Slim Framework is pretty important to your question, you should update your question to include that. Though I've covered it in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comments you mentioned you are using the [Slim framework](http://www.slimframework.com/), which has an [extension to support Twig templates](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Views).

Using the extension however, requires some additional setup though, you must install the extention, called *Slim Views*, **and also the Twig core** from within composer. Slim Views does not list Twig as a dependancy.

To get this working:

1. Use composer to get add both *Slim Views* And *Twig*

   ```
   $ php composer require slim/views

   $ php composer require twig/twig:~1.0
   ```
2. Configure your Slim Framework `$app` to use the new tempting engine.

   ```
   $view = $app->view();
   $view->parserOptions = array(
      'debug' => true,
      'cache' => dirname(__FILE__) . '/cache'
   );

   $view->parserExtensions = array(
       new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension(),
   );
   ```

At this point, Slim Framework is now using Twig when rendering pages. You can now do all of your includes and pass the variables to Twig:

```
<?php
// ./Slim_app.php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
/* 
 * foo.php contains the following:
 * <?php
 *     $foo = bar;
 *
 */
require 'foo.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'view' => new \Slim\Views\Twig()
));

$view = $app->view();
$view->parserOptions = array(
    'debug' => true,
    'cache' => dirname(__FILE__) . '/cache'
);

$view->parserExtensions = array(
    new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension(),
);

$app->get('/hello', function () use ($app, $foo) {
    //twig_template.html.twig exists in the templates directory. 
    //(./templates/twig_template.html.twig)
    $app->render('twig_template.html.twig', array('foo' => $foo));
});

$app->run();

?>
```

---

```
{# ./templates/twig_template.html.twig #}
{{ foo }}
```

Navigating to `Slim_app.php/hello` now displays the following:

[image]

[More info on using Twig.](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation)